# Make/makefile progress indication!

Tags: scripting, makefile, build-automation, progress-bar

**Look at this makefile, it has some sort of primitive progress indication (could have been a progress bar).**

**Please give me suggestions/comments on it!**

---

```
# BUILD is initially undefined
ifndef BUILD

# max equals 256 x's
sixteen := x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
MAX := $(foreach x,$(sixteen),$(sixteen))

# T estimates how many targets we are building by replacing BUILD with a special string
T := $(shell $(MAKE) -nrRf $(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)) $(MAKECMDGOALS) \
            BUILD="COUNTTHIS" | grep -c "COUNTTHIS")

# N is the number of pending targets in base 1, well in fact, base x :-)
N := $(wordlist 1,$T,$(MAX))

# auto-decrementing counter that returns the number of pending targets in base 10
counter = $(words $N)$(eval N := $(wordlist 2,$(words $N),$N))

# BUILD is now defined to show the progress, this also avoids redefining T in loop
BUILD = @echo $(counter) of $(T)
endif

# dummy phony targets

.PHONY: all clean

all: target
    @echo done

clean:
    @rm -f target *.c

# dummy build rules

target: a.c b.c c.c d.c e.c f.c g.c
    @touch $@
    $(BUILD)

%.c:
    @touch $@
    $(BUILD)
```

---

**All suggestions welcome!**

Comment: Cute trick, but I can't see wanting it.

Comment: I can. On Gentoo this would be nice. `cmake` has a built-in counter [file x / n files]. But a way to have a progress bar without flooding the screen with every command line, would be nice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This one is less intrusive and more awesome.

```
ifneq ($(words $(MAKECMDGOALS)),1)
.DEFAULT_GOAL = all
%:
        @$(MAKE) $@ --no-print-directory -rRf $(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))
else
ifndef ECHO
T := $(shell $(MAKE) $(MAKECMDGOALS) --no-print-directory \
      -nrRf $(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)) \
      ECHO="COUNTTHIS" | grep -c "COUNTTHIS")

N := x
C = $(words $N)$(eval N := x $N)
ECHO = echo "`expr " [\`expr $C '*' 100 / $T\`" : '.*\(....\)$$'`%]"
endif

.PHONY: all clean

all: target
        @$(ECHO) All done

clean:
        @rm -f target *.c
#       @$(ECHO) Clean done

target: a.c b.c c.c d.c e.c
        @$(ECHO) Linking $@
        @sleep 0.1
        @touch $@

%.c:
        @$(ECHO) Compiling $@
        @sleep 0.1
        @touch $@

endif
```

Comment: To get it to re-write the previous line use this for the ECHO line: `ECHO = echo -ne "\r `` expr " [\ `` expr $C '*' 100 / $T\ `` " : '.*\(....\)$$' `` %]"`  It works in bash, might not work on other *nixes as well.  Depends on if `echo` supports `-e` and `-n`.

Comment: Note on the previous comment the double backticks should be single backticks, like in the post.  The only addition was `-ne` after echo and `\r` after the quotes.

Comment: This is nice but the percentages break when using -j option. For example  [28%] Compiling b.c
 [14%] Compiling a.c ...

Answer (score 7):

There wasn't really a question so this is less of a standalone answer and more of an extension to Giovanni Funchai's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/455390/141023). This question is the first google result for "GNU Make Progress" so I ended up here looking for how to do this.

As pointed out by Rob Wells, the solution doesn't work for <10%, but the technique can be extended with the print formatting done by a helper script in whatever language you feel is portable enough for your build. For example, using a python helper script:

`echo_progress.py`:

```
"""
Print makefile progress
"""

import argparse
import math
import sys

def main():
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)
  parser.add_argument("--stepno", type=int, required=True)
  parser.add_argument("--nsteps", type=int, required=True)
  parser.add_argument("remainder", nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)
  args = parser.parse_args()

  nchars = int(math.log(args.nsteps, 10)) + 1
  fmt_str = "[{:Xd}/{:Xd}]({:6.2f}%)".replace("X", str(nchars))
  progress = 100 * args.stepno / args.nsteps
  sys.stdout.write(fmt_str.format(args.stepno, args.nsteps, progress))
  for item in args.remainder:
    sys.stdout.write(" ")
    sys.stdout.write(item)
  sys.stdout.write("\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

And the modified `Makefile`:

```
_mkfile_path := $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
I := $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $(_mkfile_path)))

ifneq ($(words $(MAKECMDGOALS)),1)
.DEFAULT_GOAL = all
%:
    @$(MAKE) $@ --no-print-directory -rRf $(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))
else
ifndef ECHO
T := $(shell $(MAKE) $(MAKECMDGOALS) --no-print-directory \
      -nrRf $(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)) \
      ECHO="COUNTTHIS" | grep -c "COUNTTHIS")
N := x
C = $(words $N)$(eval N := x $N)
ECHO = python $(I)/echo_progress.py --stepno=$C --nsteps=$T
endif

.PHONY: all clean

all: target
    @$(ECHO) All done

clean:
    @rm -f target *.c
#       @$(ECHO) Clean done

target: a.c b.c c.c d.c e.c f.c g.c h.c i.c j.c k.c l.c m.c n.c o.c p.c q.c \
        r.c s.c t.c u.c v.c w.c x.c y.c z.c
    @$(ECHO) Linking $@
    @sleep 0.01
    @touch $@

%.c:
    @$(ECHO) Compiling $@
    @sleep 0.01
    @touch $@

endif
```

yields:

```
$ make
[ 1/28](  3.57%) Compiling a.c
[ 2/28](  7.14%) Compiling b.c
[ 3/28]( 10.71%) Compiling c.c
[ 4/28]( 14.29%) Compiling d.c
[ 5/28]( 17.86%) Compiling e.c
[ 6/28]( 21.43%) Compiling f.c
[ 7/28]( 25.00%) Compiling g.c
[ 8/28]( 28.57%) Compiling h.c
[ 9/28]( 32.14%) Compiling i.c
[10/28]( 35.71%) Compiling j.c
[11/28]( 39.29%) Compiling k.c
[12/28]( 42.86%) Compiling l.c
[13/28]( 46.43%) Compiling m.c
[14/28]( 50.00%) Compiling n.c
[15/28]( 53.57%) Compiling o.c
[16/28]( 57.14%) Compiling p.c
[17/28]( 60.71%) Compiling q.c
[18/28]( 64.29%) Compiling r.c
[19/28]( 67.86%) Compiling s.c
[20/28]( 71.43%) Compiling t.c
[21/28]( 75.00%) Compiling u.c
[22/28]( 78.57%) Compiling v.c
[23/28]( 82.14%) Compiling w.c
[24/28]( 85.71%) Compiling x.c
[25/28]( 89.29%) Compiling y.c
[26/28]( 92.86%) Compiling z.c
[27/28]( 96.43%) Linking target
[28/28](100.00%) All done
```

One could even print a fancy progress bar with unicode characters.

Modified `echo_progress.py`:

```
"""
Print makefile progress
"""

import argparse
import math
import sys

def get_progress_bar(numchars, fraction=None, percent=None):
  """
  Return a high resolution unicode progress bar
  """
  if percent is not None:
    fraction = percent / 100.0

  if fraction >= 1.0:
    return "█" * numchars

  blocks = [" ", "▏", "▎", "▍", "▌", "▋", "▊", "▉", "█"]
  length_in_chars = fraction * numchars
  n_full = int(length_in_chars)
  i_partial = int(8 * (length_in_chars - n_full))
  n_empty = max(numchars - n_full - 1, 0)
  return ("█" * n_full) + blocks[i_partial] + (" " * n_empty)

def main():
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)
  parser.add_argument("--stepno", type=int, required=True)
  parser.add_argument("--nsteps", type=int, required=True)
  parser.add_argument("remainder", nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)
  args = parser.parse_args()

  nchars = int(math.log(args.nsteps, 10)) + 1
  fmt_str = "\r[{:Xd}/{:Xd}]({:6.2f}%) ".replace("X", str(nchars))
  progress = 100 * args.stepno / args.nsteps
  sys.stdout.write(fmt_str.format(args.stepno, args.nsteps, progress))
  sys.stdout.write(get_progress_bar(20, percent=progress))
  remainder_str = " ".join(args.remainder)
  sys.stdout.write(" {:20s}".format(remainder_str[:20]))
  if args.stepno == args.nsteps:
    sys.stdout.write("\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Which would result in something like this:

```
$ make clean && make
[12/28]( 42.86%) ███████▊             Compiling k.c
```

during progress and:

```
$ make clean && make
[28/28](100.00%) ████████████████████ All done
```

upon completion.

Comment: Nice ! Should be on top.But I think your second python code has a flaw.It uses non-ASCII characters but hasn't any encoding declaration.You have to add for example ```# coding: utf-8``` at the top of the script.See [this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).However thank you so much :)

Comment: According to Your makefile script which is very nice is there any possibity to add something like error message? For example, if we use `target` on `c.c` and response code is different than 0 which is a status for error to use different message, instead of 'Compiling c.c' use `Compiling for c.c failed', is this possible? I've tried but can't save to variable, I've tried with new variable but still can't work :(

Answer (score 6):

This is a slight modification to @GiovanniFunchal's excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/455390/999943).

So I wanted to understand this better and make it work for < 10% so I dug into the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) and learned more about [expr](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/moreadv.html#EXPRREF).

```
# PLACE AT THE TOP OF YOUR MAKEFILE
#---------------------------------
# Progress bar defs
#--------------------------------
#  words = count the number of words
ifneq ($(words $(MAKECMDGOALS)),1) # if no argument was given to make...
.DEFAULT_GOAL = all # set the default goal to all
#  http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html
#  $@ = target name
#  %: = last resort recipe
#  --no-print-directory = don't print enter/leave messages for each output grouping
#  MAKEFILE_LIST = has a list of all the parsed Makefiles that can be found *.mk, Makefile, etc
#  -n = dry run, just print the recipes
#  -r = no builtin rules, disables implicit rules
#  -R = no builtin variables, disables implicit variables
#  -f = specify the name of the Makefile
%:                   # define a last resort default rule
      @$(MAKE) $@ --no-print-directory -rRf $(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)) # recursive make call, 
else
ifndef ECHO
#  execute a dry run of make, defining echo beforehand, and count all the instances of "COUNTTHIS"
T := $(shell $(MAKE) $(MAKECMDGOALS) --no-print-directory \
      -nrRf $(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)) \
      ECHO="COUNTTHIS" | grep -c "COUNTTHIS")
#  eval = evaluate the text and read the results as makefile commands
N := x
#  Recursively expand C for each instance of ECHO to count more x's
C = $(words $N)$(eval N := x $N)
#  Multipy the count of x's by 100, and divide by the count of "COUNTTHIS"
#  Followed by a percent sign
#  And wrap it all in square brackets
ECHO = echo -ne "\r [`expr $C '*' 100 / $T`%]"
endif
#------------------
# end progress bar
#------------------

# REST OF YOUR MAKEFILE HERE

#----- Progressbar endif at end Makefile
endif
```

I got rid of the `: '.*\(....\)$$'` part. It would return the last 4 characters of the inner `expr` command, but would fail if it was less than 4. And now it works for sub 10%!

And here is the comment free version:

```
ifneq ($(words $(MAKECMDGOALS)),1) # if no argument was given to make...
.DEFAULT_GOAL = all # set the default goal to all
%:                   # define a last resort default rule
      @$(MAKE) $@ --no-print-directory -rRf $(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)) # recursive make call, 
else
ifndef ECHO
T := $(shell $(MAKE) $(MAKECMDGOALS) --no-print-directory \
      -nrRf $(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)) \
      ECHO="COUNTTHIS" | grep -c "COUNTTHIS")
N := x
C = $(words $N)$(eval N := x $N)
ECHO = echo -ne "\r [`expr $C '*' 100 / $T`%]"
endif

# ...

endif
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I used this on the Linux kernel makefile and it suppresses the output! the build still runs in the background but I can't see anything in STDOUT.

Comment: It is probably the `\r` in the echo... That keeps it on the same line each time, or the `-ne` part of the echo.

Comment: the problem persists even after removing those, maybe the kernel KBUILD scripts are doing something special that this code doesn't cover?

Answer (score 5):

Many thanks to `@Giovanni Funchal` and `@phyatt` for the question and answers!

I just simplified it even more for my own better understanding.

```
ifndef ECHO
HIT_TOTAL != ${MAKE} ${MAKECMDGOALS} --dry-run ECHO="HIT_MARK" | grep -c "HIT_MARK"
HIT_COUNT = $(eval HIT_N != expr ${HIT_N} + 1)${HIT_N}
ECHO = echo "[`expr ${HIT_COUNT} '*' 100 / ${HIT_TOTAL}`%]"
endif
```

- `!=` assigns from shell command
- `=`  evaluates variable each time it's used
- `eval` executes its argument without any output
- `expr` allows to make arithmetic calculations

( Not sure though which approach is faster: to call shell with expr or to count 'x'-es with make. )

Usage is the same:

```
target:
    @$(ECHO) $@
```

Comment: Nice to see 10 years after my original post this is still getting attention ;)

Answer (score 2):

Nice trick! (-:

But not really scalable for growing projects that are distributed across many directories with lots of makefiles.

I'd be more inclined to have logging sprinkled through the [Mm]akefiles* in your project and use that to keep track of progress.

Just a thought. BTW Thanks for sharing this.

**Edit:** Just had a thought. This could be useful in a modified form to display a throbber to show progress while a long task proceeds, e.g unpacking a large distribution tarball instead of just specifying the -v option to the tar command. Still a bit of sugar coating but a bit of fun aswell. (-:

cheers,

Rob

Comment: Thanks for your comment, can you please explain why you think this does not scales? Ok the code is just a sketch, but MAX can hold 64k x's if needed, and the calculation of the T variable is quite fast.

Comment: It doesn't scale because it won't work if you use make over multiple directories, with each sub-directory having it's own makefile.

Comment: @ScottieT812, cheers, that was the main reason for my comment! (-: The other one is continually having to calculate and update the number of x's needed as the project expands. Still. nice trick though.

Comment: Rob you did not understood my script. It WORKS if you have makefiles over multiple directories (although I do not recommend recursive make) and the x's are NOT number of targets, its just an upper-bound (256, can be more). The exact number of targets is automatically discovered (see code of $T)